# Need of 8GB RAM if 2GB RAM can do the work using Virtual Memory

Tags: linux, ram, virtual-memory

What is the necessity of 8GB RAM if we can accomplish the work using 2GB RAM using Virtual Memory?

Comment: This doesn't sound related to programming, and would probably be better posted on https://superuser.com/.

Comment: 640K should be enough for anyone

Comment: @Nemo-Nice comment,but you should have explained the reason too for OP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual memory involves using the disk to emulate additional RAM.  This results in lower performance because you're swapping out pages of RAM, writing them to the disk, and then reading other pages of RAM from the disk before you can do anything with the data stored in those pages.  If you have 8GB of RAM however, (theoretically) you wouldn't use the disk at all and the operations would be faster as you simply have to access the memory location.